# How to get the integration key for free-trail account

Tags: docusignapi

At present in my trail free account, we don't have the option to generate the Integration Key. I would like to know, couple of details here.

1) How to get the integration key for free trail account.

2) Do we need to upgrade the current licence to generate the Integration key? If yes, Please share the plan and pricing details.

Comment: This question doesn't belong SO as it doesn't pertain to coding. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) including the link "How to ask questions the smart way."

Answer (score 0):

Complete instructions are found here in the DocuSign API documentation: https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/integrator_key.html.